# How to update database `jsonb` column during migration in EF Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

I develop ASP.NET Core application and use EF code first approach. Application have already deployed to the production and we have user data. Now we updated the model of column which has type `jsonb`. So, we need to refresh this column in existing records acording to the new model. What is the best approach for such update? Is it possible somehow to make this with EF migration mechanism?

Comment: did you able to find the solution for this problem

Comment: I'm getting an error, even though I've implemented the HasConversion to serialize/deserialize class to json